# Android app not playing mp3 (locally stored mp3s)

Tags: android, html, cordova, audio

I have a phonegap app and I'm trying to play mp3's which are stores in the app's folder like this:

```
--App Root

   -- audio

      -- mp3s

      --Mp3's are all here
```

Now, the problem is only with Android because it works fine in IOS. On android I'm getting the audio player but no sound is coming out.

Here is the code:

```
//JS

var 

audiofile = 'audio/mp3s/'+result.text+'en.mp3';

//HTML

<audio class="audioPlayer" controls>
    <source src="'+audiofile+'" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android you may need to prefix the path to the file with "/android_asset"

So use "/android_asset/audio/mp3s/" as the base directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug the app with chrome Inspect Devices (DevTools little menu), and see if there are any errors.